# Null Geodesics in Anti-de Sitter space time

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

[image: Geodesics of AdS spacetime.]

Would anyone be able to explain how the step was taken in getting the final equation with $R \tan(t/R)$

I understand the steps before where we are finding the null geodesic equation for the AdS space time but not sure how the final equation is produced.

**Note**: This question is using a coordinate transformed metric of AdS with transformation $r=R \sinh \rho$ as shown at the top.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for letting me know, will do for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the differential relation

$$(\cosh\rho)\,\dot t=R\dot\rho$$

between $t$ and $\rho$ to get

$$\frac{dt}{R}=\frac{d\rho}{\cosh\rho}.$$

Then integrate to get

$$\frac{t}{R}=\tan^{-1}{(\sinh\rho)}$$

or

$$\sinh\rho=\tan\frac{t}{R}.$$